# Localstorage little help needed

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I've been trying to understand `localstorage` and encountered a little problem.
When I add the following code the number will be zero everything I refresh the site until I press the button. But I want it to show the up-to-date number when I have refreshed the site.

```
function CollectCoin() {
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (localStorage.clickcount) {
            localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
        } else {
            localStorage.clickcount = 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Total coins: " + localStorage.clickcount;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me with this issue and explain to me what to do to fix this.

Comment: your function works for me.

Comment: wait!? What is he asking? He wants to show it not by clicking the button right? http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_webstorage_local_clickcount

Comment: Strange starts with 0 coins everytime i refresh the page :(

Comment: @Stanley1943 that's where i got the code from! but i want the number to increase with the button but also want it to show when i refresh where i left of so people won't get confused so to speak.

Comment: Your code is working for me.  Are you certain that you are not resetting the value of `localStorage.clickcount` somewhere else, in another piece of code?

Comment: @davidTansey well i have in my html part <div id="result">Total coins: 0</div>
<button onclick="CollectCoin()">Collect Coins</button> but i don't think that's the problem and the js i posted it all i have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want it to display the number. That is more complicated than the simple function

https://jsfiddle.net/ed5unzf6/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="result">Total coins: 0</div>
<button id="coinButton">Collect Coins</button>
```

Javascript:

```
//Check if Local Storage is available
if (typeof(Storage) == 'undefined'){
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
}else{

  display(); //display the coin count
  //when user click the button, it adds 1
  document.getElementById('coinButton').addEventListener('click', addcoin);
}

function addcoin() {
  localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
  display();
}

//display function
function display() {

  //Check if clickcount is available. Only Number is tested, so use isNaN
  if (!localStorage.clickcount || isNaN(localStorage.clickcount)){
    localStorage.clickcount = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Total coins: " + Number(localStorage.clickcount);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, this is what i was looking for:)

Answer (score 0):

Please see it working here : https://jsfiddle.net/nueffmvm/

```
function CollectCoin() {
    if(localStorage) {
        if(localStorage.clickCount == "NaN"){
          localStorage.clickCount = 1;
        }
        else{
          localStorage.clickCount++;
        }
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Total coins: " + localStorage.clickCount;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
    }
}
```

Comment: With this it doesn't even increment even more. Thanks for the reply tho:)

Comment: check the modified answer with fiddle